# To show a random variable is geometric

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

If $X$ is exponential with rate $\lambda$, show that $Y= [X]+1$ is geometric with parameter $p= 1 - e^{-\lambda}$, where $[x]$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.

I dont know hot to approach. 
I understand that $[X]$ will give a step function with integer values  ...

Comment: How about trying mgf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\{[X] = x\}\iff\{x\leq X<x+1\}.$$
Then you want to examine the $P(Y = y)$, which is

> $$P(Y=y) = P([X]+1 = y) = P([X] = y-1).$$

Hopefully, you can take it from there.

Comment: Also, to get full credit/understanding, make sure you specify the range of $Y$.